# Variable pass page

Tags: php, variables

I want pass variable across pages

Example: page 1

```
$x = 'name' ;
<form action='page 2' method='get'> 
    <input type='submit' name='y' value='go' />
</form>`
```

page 2

```
$y = $x ;
echo $y ;
```

I want to when you press submit. It will pass variable and its value to page 2. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please always try to use 'post' method for submitting data, as it is more secure than 'get' method. So, i am using 'post' method in your updated code.

Please find the updated code below:

```
<?php $x = "name" ; ?>

<form action="page 2" method="post" name="form1"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="x" value="<?php echo $x; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="y" value="go" />
</form>
```

On page 2, recieve the value by using the superglobal '$_POST', just like this:

```
<?php $y = $_POST['x'];
echo $y; ?>
```

I hope, this may be helpful to you.